# The difference between "past" and "passed" in the following sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it proper to say "past" or "passed" in this sentence?

> Hopefully I can stay up passed or past midnight.

Comment: A dictionary would answer this question quicker for you.

Answer (score 2):

*Passed* is the past-tense form as well as the past participle of the verb *to pass* while *past* in this particular context would be a preposition and as a preposition it means *beyond in time* or *later than* (you can look this word up in any good online dictionary to make sure that what I'm saying is valid information). *Stay up passed midnight* doesn't really make a whole lot of sense here. So, realistically speaking, your only option is *past*:

> Hopefully, I can stay up **past** midnight.

Comment: Past and passed are often confused, even by native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

"Passed" is a verb meaning that one thing went by another. Like, "While I was standing on the corner, a car passed me." The thing could "go by" either physically, like in that example, or in time, like, "I wanted to ask her on a date, but the opportunity had passed."

"Past" can be a noun referring to a time before the present. Like, "In history class, we study the past."

"Past" can also be an adjective indicating that something relates to a time before the present. "Don't bring up past arguments."

Or as here, it can be a preposition, meaning beyond in time or position. "The ball landed past the goal post." "I stayed up past midnight."

The two words are pronounced the same and have related meanings, so I can see it being confusing. Like you could say, "I was waiting for the clock to strike midnight, but the time passed me and I didn't notice." Or more simply, "Midnight passed me."

Comment: Speaking from a British - South African background, I'd have said: **time passed me by** rather than just **passed me**. Does that strike your ear as strange?

Comment: @RonaldSole No, "time passed me by" is common in American English also. Whether we include the "by" depends on the context of the sentence. As a complete sentence, we'd say, "Time passed me by." But, "The time available to apply for the job passed me." I'm not sure if there's a general rule.